# Cannot open React build file directly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm new to React. After I build my app, I can serve my app locally using `serve -s build`, but I cannot open it directly by double clicking index.html because I'll get

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Based on my understanding, React apps are also essentially HTML CSS and js files. I'm wondering what's the problem.

Comment: Please add more context to this question, i.e: <script> tag inside index.html. webpack.config.js and your folder structure.

Comment: Where is it looking for your javascript bundle? where is it actually located on your disk? obviously those two paths don't line up.

Answer (score 0):

That's normal!
the build bundle is used for deploy to server by some tools such as tomcat,
not used for static html file.
their path is incorrect.